# In Bootstrap4 input-group helptext does not display as block

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a page that uses Bootstrap 4 with a single input control that was working okay. My problem is when I add help it adds it on the same line rather than the next line beneath the control as I would expect.

My suspicion is it that it is a problem with input-group/form-group. Im finding the generally very good Bootstrap documenentation very unclear on how these two things fit together since Im using inputgroups as the field label.

This is the html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
        <label for="undoLocation" id="undoLocationlabel" class="input-group-text">
            Find songs 
        </label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" name="undoLocation" id="undoLocation" aria-describedby="undoLocationHELP">

            <option value="0">
                that are currently in the selected locations
            </option>
            <option selected="selected" value="1">
                that were originally in the selected locations
            </option>

    </select>
    <small id="undoLocationHELP" class="form-text text-muted">
        When files have been moved by SongKong you can use this option to find files currently in the selected all location or find files that were originally in the selected location
    </small>
</div>
```

and I have created a jsfiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/paultaylor/g64v96fy/1/

Comment: the documentation is pretty clear to me: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/ there is a concise example labeled "Your vanity URL"

Comment: @soulshined that shows an inputgroup fine, but not with help text and it is the help text that is causing the issue !

Comment: "Your vanity URL" is not considered help text to you? What do you mean by helptext?

Comment: its just a regular label, its not help text as described in the forms section, help text is usually  longer than just the simple field label And its before the input in my case it is after the input

Comment: I understand now. Then you just have a simple fix. Your `input-group` div encloses all the elements and thereby applying those styles to it. If you don't want it to be inline with those elements, just move it below that div.

Comment: ah right okay i see, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Bootstrap [discussion](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#block-level):

> Block help text—for below inputs or for longer lines of help text—can be easily achieved with .form-text. This class includes display: block and adds some top margin for easy spacing from the inputs above.

However, you added it to a parent element with a `input-group` class, by nature will display with the group, inline.  Additionally, you used an HTML default inline tag `<small>` which also displays, by nature, inline.

Per [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-small-element):

> The small element should not be used for extended spans of text, such as multiple paragraphs, lists, or sections of text. It is only intended for short runs of text...

Even if you do what's recommended and wrap it in a `<p>` tag, the parent still defines the style, and input-groups by nature are inline.
So, it's recommended to move it outside of the div.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-prepend">
    <label for="undoLocation" id="undoLocationlabel" class="input-group-text">
       Find songs 
    </label>
  </div>
  <select class="custom-select" name="undoLocation" id="undoLocation" aria-describedby="undoLocationHELP">
    <option value="0">that are currently in the selected locations</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="1">that were originally in the selected locations</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p id="undoLocationHELP" class="form-text text-muted">
  When files have been moved by SongKong you can use this option to find files currently in the selected all location or find files that were originally in the selected location
</p>
```